# How to get xcode instruments logging for a duration

Tags: ios, xcode, logging, android-activity, monitor

I could log a csv file from *Xcode - > Instruments -> Activity Monitor -> Instrument - > 'Export Track for ...'*.

It creates the log file for the current instant only.

**I need to get the CPU % usage graph for a particular duration.**

> (from start of execution to end of execution of my application).

Is there a way to get the log file for selected duration?

Please give your idea.